Fedex API Returns Transaction ID with no other data
I am using the below VBA to call the Fedex API to get shipping status. I am able to use similar code to get the token.  That's working.
When I try to get the data by tracking number I get a TransactionID and nothing in the output.
ResponseText Example: "{"transactionId":"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","output":{}}"
The same results happen in Dev and Prod.  Am I missing something in the request body?
Sub TrackFedExPackage()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim accessToken As String
    Dim trackingNumber As String
    Dim requestBody As String
    Dim responseText As String

    accessToken = GetFedExOAuthToken()
    trackingNumber = "1234567890123"
    url = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers"
    'url = "https://apis.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers?"

    ' Create the JSON request body
    requestBody = "{""trackingInfo"": [{""trackingNumber"": """ & trackingNumber & """}]}"

    ' Create XMLHTTP object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    ' Open the connection
    With xmlhttp
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send requestBody
    End With

    ' Get the response
    responseText = xmlhttp.responseText

    ' Display the response
    MsgBox responseText

    ' Clean up
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub

I have tried to find other examples of vba, C#, JavaScript and more and the codes look similar.
Here is the token function
Function GetFedExOAuthToken() As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim requestBody As String
    Dim clientId As String
    Dim clientSecret As String
    Dim responseText As String
    
    ' Your FedEx API credentials
    clientId = "ClientidDev" 'Dev
    clientSecret = "clientSecretDev" 'Dev
    
    
    ' Create HTTP object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Set the URL for the OAuth token request
    url = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token" 'Dev
    'url = "https://apis.fedex.com/oauth/token" 'Prod
    
    ' Construct the request body
    requestBody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & clientId & "&client_secret=" & clientSecret
    
    ' Send the request
    With http
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send requestBody
        responseText = .responseText
    End With

    ' Extract the access token from the response
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(responseText)
    GetFedExOAuthToken = json("access_token")

    ' Clean up
    Set http = Nothing
    Set json = Nothing
End Function


Maybe "includeDetailedScans": true needs to be added to the request? ... at least that what it looks like based on their request example here on the right side of the page.

I have added that to the request body but I get the same results.      requestBody = "{""trackingInfo"": [{" & """trackingNumber"": """ & trackingNumber & """, " & """includeDetailedScans"": " & IIf(detailedscans, "true", "false") & "}]}"

I figured it out.  I had to change the request body to       requestBody = "{""trackingInfo"": [ {" & """trackingNumberInfo""" & ": {" & """trackingNumber""" & ": """ & trackingNumber & """}}], " & """includeDetailedScans"" : " & IIf(detailedscans, "true", "false") & "}"
